# Modifying an existing class: should I extend it to a new class?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, inheritance, class

I'm working with a library (from an online source, not authored in-house) providing an interface as well as an implementation of it:

```
interface FooInterface {
   // ...
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {
  // ...
}
```

I'm not satisfied with the default implementation, `Foo`, so I can always write something like:

```
class MyFoo implements FooInterface {
  // ...
}
```

However, the changes I want are very small; and in fact, if any new behaviour/feature comes in an updated version of the library, this is desired unless there is very good reason not to. At this point, I have two choices:

- Duplicate the entirety of `Foo` into `MyFoo` except for the changed parts, and keep it updated from time to time with the changes in the library.
- Inherit `Foo` into `MyFoo` and make minimal modifications in `MyFoo`.

Which of the above two practices would be encouraged from a software engineering perspective?

Comment: Why are you making modifications? There's a third option - wrap an instance of Foo inside an instance of MyFoo and use delegate methods. I would say that duplicating Foo into MyFoo is almost never the right solution, so in an OO environment, you're left with inheritance or composition. Without knowing what types of changes you're making or how you will be using these two classes, it's hard to say which one is the best option.

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to your code ? Which methods are in `FooInterface` ? In which methods do you need to add behaviour in `MyFoo` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Foo` documents the ways it may be extended, and you can achieve what you want by extending `Foo`, then that's the way to go. However it's possible `Foo` wasn't meant to be inherited from and the author simply neglected to make the class `sealed`/`final`. In that case you *shouldn't* inherit from `Foo`, because your subclass may break if `Foo` is refactored in a later version of the library.

For example, `Foo.bar` may be implemented in terms of `Foo.baz` now, but that's just an implementation detail. You coded your subclass under this assumption. In the next release, `bar` no longer calls `baz` and your subclass breaks. The reverse could also happen `bar` didn't call `baz` and now it suddenly does. This is known as the Fragile Base Class problem.

There's a third option you didn't mention, which is using composition: your implementation of `FooInterface` holds a reference to an instance of `Foo` and uses that to get the job done. If `Foo` isn't meant to be extended then this is the route I would recommend if possible.

If even that's not possible consider contacting the author of the library and asking if the feature you need can be implemented (or implement it yourself and send them a patch/pull request). That way it becomes part of the library and you don't have to worry about your own implementation differing from future releases.

Comment: Would composition be better at managing `Foo.bar` changing its implementation? Assuming there is no *sealed* or *final*, isn't calling `innerFoo.bar()` the same as calling `super()` in an overridden `bar`?

Comment: @coredump It does make a difference. To make things more concrete, let's say we're implementing `Set`s and the methods are `addAll` (which takes a collection) and `add` (single element) instead. `BaseSet.addAll` is implemented in terms of `add`. You create a `CountingSet` subclass that keeps an integer variable for keeping track of the number of elements in the set. You know `addAll` calls `add` for each element in the collection so you only override `add` and increment the variable there. Next release `addAll` no longer calls `add`. The base class still does what it promised...

Comment: @coredump ...but your subclass breaks. If you used composition you'd be fine because you would no longer be relying on superclass methods calling your overrides.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the code do you want to change. If you aren't satisfied with almost all the method implementations, you should just write your own implementation of the whole class.

- But it is better to inherit `MyFoo` from `Foo`, if its a small change. You will be able to keep a track of the changes you had to make. Also, you won't break any design patterns the code might be using via the interface.
- It's not a good idea to duplicate the entire `Foo` into `MyFoo`. That way, every time `Foo` class modifies any method implementations or adds new ones, you will have to make changes to your `MyFoo` class to make them available to your code. It is always better to reuse code by referencing to it rather than duplicating it.